# WPF c# how to add a user control to a panel children dynamically that bubbles/tunnels from UC to Panel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, routed-events

I have created a usercontrol (named `UCDataGrid`) that I want to add to my Main Window at runtime.

In MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
private void GetAnotherUserControl(string sUCName)
{
    var UC_Grid = new UCDataGrid();

    ...

    // Add to 'PositioningGrid' Grid Layout
    PositioningGrid.Children.Add(UC_Grid);

    // Register UC_Grid Name
    PositioningGrid.RegisterName(sUCName, UC_Grid);

    ...
}
```

In MainWindow.XAML [Structure]:

```
Grid (named “TopGrid”) -> Grid (named “PostioningGrid”)
```

The `PositioningGrid` will hold the children controls/user controls I develop which shall be added dynamically at runtime depending on Business rules.

By adding my user control in this fashion, how can I do bubbling/tunneling when I click on a checkbox in my dynamically added usercontrol?

I want to click the checkbox in my usercontrol (`UCDataGrid`) and run code from my MainWindow.

I have tried several ways but would like to know if there is some way to notify my MainWindow that the user has clicked on the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the `CheckBox.Checked` routed event in the window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        ...
        Title="Window7" Height="300" Width="300" CheckBox.Checked="Window_Checked">
```

Or:

```
 this.AddHandler(CheckBox.CheckedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Window_Checked));
```

The `Checked` event will bubble up from the `CheckBox` to the parent window.